# sipdroid - Multiple call handling

Tags: sip

I just installed **SIPDROID**. I made three account in sip2sip.(free SIP provider). 

Then after I have configured application using one of that account. Application works fine.

**Question is:** If I make multiple call to the same phone using **SIP** is there anyway to handle all calls at a same time?

Multiple call on the same phone seems not working. The first call getting picked up but what about the second call which is coming during first call is going on.

Even second call is not displaying on the screen.
Confused !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sipdroid](http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/) that I what started with but after researching on it and from developers reviews I found that application has some missing functionality like multiple call and transferring calls etc...

I don't know but may who is **expert in sip stack or have time to do** can implement missing functionality but I am neither one of them so my desire to get an application that have all this functionality and by modifying it I can integrate into my application and [csipsimple](http://codes.google.com/p/csipsimple/) is the answer.

However its not easy job to build csipsimple into windows environment but there is hack how to do it. so carefully read its [wiki](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/wiki/HowToBuild#For_Windows) about building project into window environment.

According to wiki you can [build native library](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/wiki/HowToBuild#Build_native_library) or you can go ahead [without building the native library](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/wiki/HowToBuild#Without_building_the_native_library). I suggest for windows user to go with  [without building the native library](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/wiki/HowToBuild#Without_building_the_native_library).

If you have read wiki then in *"without building the native library"* section last line is like

> "*To get the .so files, download latest nightly build from nightly
>   build website and unpack the apk file (apk files are just zip files).
>   Then get lib/ARCH/.so files and copy it into CSipSimple
>   libs/ARCH/.so*"

**I have to clarify one important thing about that:**

First get [.apk](http://nightlies.csipsimple.com/trunk/) file of csipsimple. The version of ***.apk*** file must same to download version of your [csipsimple source code.](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/source/browse/trunk/CSipSimple).

Here, you can see the source code version. Download the same version [.apk](http://nightlies.csipsimple.com/trunk/) and do further as described in wiki.
[image]